# Error while installing botframework-webchat library in React

Tags: reactjs, npm, botframework, npm-install, web-chat

I am trying to create a new React Application using "botframework-webchat" library but I am getting the below error while running the command `npm install botframework-webchat`

```
Run `npm audit` for details.
PS C:\Users\repo\custom_react> npm install botframework-webchat  
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree
npm ERR!
npm ERR! While resolving: custom_react@0.1.0
npm ERR! Found: react@17.0.2
npm ERR! node_modules/react
npm ERR!   react@"^17.0.2" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer react@"16.8.6" from botframework-webchat@4.13.0
npm ERR! node_modules/botframework-webchat
npm ERR!   botframework-webchat@"*" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
```

Can anyone guide me how to resolve this error please?

Comment: can anyone help me to resolve this issue here?

Comment: Did you find a solution? I'm having the same issue